# How can I increment a wrapped around integer? (0-360 angle sensor wraparound)

Tags: arduino

I have an angle sensor that reads 0-360, it's an absolute position sensor. The value can only read 0-360, then starts back at 0 past 360. Values below 0 wraps back around to 360.

I'm using this sensor in a 17:1 gear ratio application (1 steering wheel rotation in a car = 17~ 360 degree rotations as seen by sensor). The steering wheel can rotate several times lock to lock.

The angle sensor doesn't always read angles linearly (0,1,2,3...360,0) as the angle updates can skip numbers based on RPM (but thankfully, won't miss an entire rotation). So, I can't write code to increment/decrement based on absolute 0/360 crossing.

I'm struggling to write some code to handle the wraparound, as I need to "read" angles greater than "360 degrees".

Much research into wraparound values for Arduino refer to the time since boot overflow. This doesn't apply to my application.

The goal is a variable that contains the total sensor reading as a signed int.

Comment: This is a math problem. Read about modulus arithmetic, the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and Z/nZ field, i.e. [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

First, 0° and 360° is the same angle. Isn't it 0 to 359°?

Why not extend the zero crossing detection like this:

```
angle += sensor

If 240<=lastsensor<=359 and 0<=sensor<=120:
    angle +=360
If 240<=sensor<=359 and 0<=lastsensor<=120:
    angle -= 360
lastsensor=sensor
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once too but with 24h hour day.

If your sensor always reports jumps (far) less than 180° mechanical difference between each sample, then it will work.

```
diff = currentsensor - lastsensor

if Math.Abs(diff) < 180 // no wrapparound
    angle += diff;
else // wraparound (diff >= 180) // values around 180 are critical, was it a wrap around or not?
    diff = -1 * Math.Sign(diff) * (360 - Math.Abs(diff)) // so 181 ... 359 --> -179 ... -1 or -181 ... -359 --> +179 ... +1
    angle += diff;

lastsensor = currrentsensor
```